# How can I publish a KML tour that is shown in a browser?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth-plugin

Till recently, it was easy to show a (Google Earth) KML tour in a browser. The KML file showed a film along a route (via sattelite).

Google changed working with external KML's.

Previously I could 'fly' along the route - as if the spectator was within an aeroplane during 5 minutes.

How can I show a (Google Earth) KML tour easily for other people in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you find a better solution. Please let me know in advance and I will remove this solution with pleasure.

Record (with a screen capturer) Google Earth while playing a route. Afterwards post it to Youtube etc.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I show a (Google Earth) KML tour easily for other people in a
>   browser?

If you want to instantly view the KML on the browser, use [this website](http://display-kml.appspot.com/). Just place the KML codes on the textfield and you're ready to go. Try this KML file:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Placemark>
<name>Simple placemark</name>
<description>Attached to the ground. Intelligently places itself 
at the height of the underlying terrain.</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

If you're writing your own implementation, know that [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut?csw=1#for-more-information) is still supported by [Javascript Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#overview).

Comment: Thank you, useful. In Google Earth I first created a route. Previously I could 'fly' along the route - as if the spectator was within an aeroplane during 5 minutes. I think that is not possible via the website and Javascript solution. Do you have further suggestions?

Comment: I think since Google Earth is deprecated many of the weblinks pertaining to it doesnt work anymore. However it is [availabe for download](http://www.google.com/earth/learn/) and the [KML tours](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148174?hl=en&ref_topic=4380577) are still present there. Feel free to explore the site.

Comment: Another solution is record Google Earth while playing a route, posting it to Youtube etc. @Noogui: gave you at least +1 for your ideas.